# Error to Connecting MongoDB Invalid scheme

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My connection string is find also but I am getting this of error

```
Error: Error connecting to db: Invalid scheme, expected connection string to start with "mongodb://" or "mongodb+srv://"
```

[image]

I also tried to update update mongoose but I am still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Since your URI is found but malformed it seems to me like the problem is the variable itself.

Please make sure your connection string follows this format `mongodb://<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/<DBNAME>` and definitely starts with `mongodb://` or `mongodb+srv://` as the error message states.

Another possible cause which seems to be quite common is a ";" at the end of connection strings. If that is the case try to remove that and retry executing the app.

It is kinda shooting into the blue right now though.